# Replace All char in a string of an object in a list c#

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of object of this class

```
public MyClass{
string code;
string other;
string other2;
}
```

i want to replace all char in code property with a custom char Ex: 'X' ,except last 4 chars, and return the modified list.
Possible using linq or not a lot of lines of code?

```
List<MyClass> classes = new List<MyClass>();
classes = //something that populate the list
classes.Select( e => ???? )
return classes; // returning the modified list
```

Comment: What would you like to replace? Is there any pattern? Please, be more specific and provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
classes = classes
    .Select(c => {
        c.code = new string('X', c.code.Length - 4) + c.code.Substring(c.code.length - 4);
        return c;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i need to return a List<MyClass>, in this way i return a string list, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

use classes.foreach(x => {ur logic here..possibly a method inside MyClass})

Comment: classes.foreach(c => c.code = new string('X', c.code.Length - 4) + c.code.Substring(c.code.length - 4))